# ajv: fail validation in case of undefined field

Tags: undefined, jsonschema, json-schema-validator, ajv

If I analyze an object with explicit undefined fields (even the not required ones), I want the JSON Schema validation to fail.

It works as expected using z-schema package, but not with ajv.

Can I have the same behavior with ajv?

Here is a code example explaining the different outputs:

```
// run `node index.js` in the terminal
const Ajv = require('ajv');
const ajvOptions = {};
const ajv = new Ajv(ajvOptions);

const ZSchema = require('z-schema');
const zSchemaOptions = {};
const validator = new ZSchema(zSchemaOptions);

const schema = {
  type: 'object',
  properties: {
    notUndefinedString: {
      type: 'string',
    },
  },
  required: [],
};


const testObject = {
  notUndefinedString: undefined,
};

const ajvValid = ajv.validate(schema, testObject);
console.log('ajv -> is valid: ', ajvValid); // true, but should be false!

const zSchemaValid = validator.validate(testObject, schema);
console.log('ZSchema -> is valid: ', zSchemaValid); // false
```

working code running here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-ajv-vs-zschema-example?file=index.js

Comment: JSON Schema works within the constraints of the JSON data model. For consistent interoperable validation, we can't require `undefined` to be used that way. I'd argue that ajv is behaving as expected here, and zschema is incorrect. If you used built in functions to convert to JSON first, what would you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems not possible at the moment.

Marked as a limitation on [GitHub](https://github.com/ajv-validator/ajv/issues/2152)